# NDVI from Composite Band using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, ndvi, landsat-8, composite

I am using ArcMap.

I created a composite band for each 5-year using band i.e.,2,3,4,5,6,7,8. I then calculated NDVI index and created NDVI map for each 5 years. I now wanted to create NDVI map of 5 years into a single NDVI map from created 5 NDVI map previously.

If that is possible, then what are the steps to be followed?